# How do I get this code to enter multiple values back into the database

Tags: php, html, multiple-select, multipleselection

I have been fiddling around with this code for a while and I cannot get it to work!  I am a bit of a noob with this type of coding so please bare that in mind if/when I ask any "stupid questions".

Basically I would like user to be able to select more than one option from a list generated from the db and feed that back in as their selection.  At the moment it is a multiple select box but it only enters one value back into the db.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
function ProjectTheme_get_categories($taxo, $selected = "", $include_empty_option = "", $ccc = "")
{
$args = "orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=0";
$terms = get_terms( $taxo, $args );

$ret = '<select multiple size="20" name="'.$taxo.'_cat" class="'.$ccc.'" id="scrollselect '.$ccc.'">';
if(!empty($include_empty_option)) $ret .= "<option value=''>".$include_empty_option."</option>";

if(empty($selected)) $selected = -1;

foreach ( $terms as $term )
{
    $id = $term->term_id;

    $ret .= '<option '.($selected == $id ? "selected='selected'" : " " ).' value="'.$id.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';

    $args = "orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=".$id;
    $sub_terms = get_terms( $taxo, $args ); 

    foreach ( $sub_terms as $sub_term )
    {
        $sub_id = $sub_term->term_id; 
        $ret .= '<option '.($selected == $sub_id ? "selected='selected'" : " " ).' value="'.$sub_id.'">&nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp;  '.$sub_term->name.'</option>';

        $args2 = "orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=".$sub_id;
        $sub_terms2 = get_terms( $taxo, $args2 );   

        foreach ( $sub_terms2 as $sub_term2 )
        {
            $sub_id2 = $sub_term2->term_id; 
            $ret .= '<option '.($selected == $sub_id2 ? "selected='selected'" : " " ).' value="'.$sub_id2.'">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
             '.$sub_term2->name.'</option>';

        }
    }

}

$ret .= '</select>';

return $ret;

}
```

Just in case I was not very clear my question is:

How do I get the code above to enter multiple values back into the database?

Comment: Have you considered just adding `[]` (giving: `name="'.$taxo.'_cat[]"`) to the name of the `select` element to return an array to the handling-script?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks very much for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this addition means it doesn't select any category